# Using two arrays to populate new text file

Tags: vb.net

How would I go about populating a text file with only the years not found in a previous text file. I think something is wrong with my For Loop. When I run the program and create the file the only year that shows up is "2015" when really there should be many and the first year  starting is "1792".

An example line from the text file I'm pulling from is "Henry,Baldwin,Andrew Jackson,PA,1830,1844"

"The first Supreme Court justice was appointed in 1789. Write a program to create a file that lists the years from 1789 through 2015 in which no Supreme Court justices were appointed. The first four lines of the file will be 1792, 1794, 1795 and 1797."

Thanks for any and all help.

```
Public Class frmJustices

Private Sub btnJusticesAppointed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnJusticesAppointed.Click
    Dim justices() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Justices.txt")
    Dim possibleYears() As String = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(String), 0)

    For i As Integer = 1789 To 2015
        ReDim possibleYears(i)
        possibleYears(i) = CStr(i)
    Next

    Dim queryYears = From year In justices
                     Let abbrev = year.Split(","c)(4)
                     Order By abbrev
                     Select abbrev

    IO.File.WriteAllLines("NoAppointments.txt", possibleYears.Except(queryYears))

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That for loop with the REDIM doesnt do what you think it does.  Look into `Enumerable.Range()`